# Dashboard on Android App against design guidelines?

Tags: android, design

Is the dashboard pattern against the Android 4 Design Guidelines? (http://d.android.com/design)

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your question, but what do you want to know?

Comment: I wanna know, if the Dashboard Pattern (you know what a  Dashboard is? This: http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/output_dashboard1.png) is against the official Android Design Guidelines from Google. 
Its not referred in the guide.

Comment: I know what a dashboard is - check, but I still don't understand what this question does on this Q&A site. How is this question related to User Experience?

Comment: A 'dashboard' isn't anything specific. It's a generic term for a broad variety of UI implementations.

Comment: The dashboard pattern is not against the Android 4 Design Guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen many dashboard implementations of quite popular android apps. So I don't think Dashboard pattern is against the Android 4 Design Guidelines.

However dashboard performances can be an issue, if you are making lot processing to produce dashboard UI elements. This could lead to exceeding approved memory limit.

Comment: Thanks! I asked, because I havent seen many dashboards in Android apps, especially in apps that use the holo theme.